# How to know which version of ADT we are using in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, version, adt

Can any one tell, how to know  which version of ADT plugin I am using in eclipse?

And which version of Android SDK I am using?

Please let me know I am new to Android.

Answer (score 61):

> For ADT Version:

(**Windows**) Go to Eclipse menu `Help >> About Eclipse`

(**For MAC**) About Eclipse is not under Help menu. Go to Eclipse near Apple symbol on top Left.

(**For MAC**) Go to Eclipse >> About Eclipse

A window opens and here click on Green Android Robot icon. A next winodw opens in which you can find the version of Android ADT.

> And for the SDK Verson:

Go to Eclipse menu `Window >> Android SDK and AVD Manager`

A window opens and in this select `Installed packages` there you can find all information about SDK.

Answer (score 4):

go to

Help -> Install new softwares -> Click on Hyperlink "What is already installed".

You can see the version from here..

Best way to upgrade is check for updates from help menu.

Answer (score 3):

For **Mac**:

Click **Eclipse** on the Menu.

Then select **About Eclipse SDK** to open the about window

Select the Android Dev Toolkit icon (the android icon).  You will then find the current version in the version column of the table.

Answer (score 2):

open eclipse

```
 **Help -> about Eclipse -> Installation Detail**
```

after clicking on Installation detail then it open a new window. it contain all the software with version which is installed in your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps...
Open Eclipse
go to Menu
Help -> Installation Detail
and below is Image where you can find your Answer[image]