# manifest file is generated with missing intent-filter tag

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

i newly installed eclipse and the sdk, and now i noticed that, every time i create a new android project the following lines are always missing from the newly created project and i have to append them manually

```
<intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is there any way to let these lines generrated automatically every time i create a new project instead of adding them manually?

Comment: When going through the new eclipse project wizard, are you checking the box to create an activity? If you don't create an activity with the wizard then there's nowhere to add the intent filter.

Comment: What version of the ADT are you using?

Comment: @MCeley: i create the activity through wizard but i have not seen any check boxes related to intents

Comment: @Alexander:how to check the version ADT??

Comment: In more detail than I can put in a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454826/how-to-know-which-version-of-adt-we-are-using-in-eclipse

Comment: In ADT 20 you should see New Android Application -> Configure Launcher Icon -> Create Activity.  On the Create Activity page, if you don't check the box to create an activity then no activity or intent filter will be setup.  If you check the box to create a blank activity then you should be good.

Comment: i dont see any check boxes except in the wizard's first page to check if the activity is a library or not and aother to check boxes non of them related to intents or similar to