# How to check ADT PlugIn Version?

Tags: android, adt

I am new to Android,

I have installed the Android Development tools successfully, but i am unable to find which ADT version i have installed. Please guide me the procedure for checking the ADT version.

Comment: Are you talking about Eclipse?

Answer (score 7):

Click on the *Help* menu and select *About Eclipse SDK*

That will bring up this popup:
[image]

In it, click on the button with the Android logo in (highlighted red) which will bring up:

[image]

This will show you the current installed ADT version.

Alternatively, you can also go to the *Help* menu -> *Install New Software*. Then select the ADT Plugins from the *Work with* section, expand the *Developer Tools* option and see the version currently installed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454875/1503130 with reference to this answer.

[image]

- Open Eclipse and click help as shown in the image

[image: Android icon]

- Click on the android icon below

[image: check the adt version]

- Look at the adt version in red box.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Eclipse IDE, then just follow these steps,

- Go to Windows Menu, Select "Android SDK Manager"
- It will open the SDK Manager's dialog box as follows,
- See the SDK version in red circle ( which is your ADT Version )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse goto Help -> About -> and select the ADT icon to view installation details.